# Pacman complains "database 'core' does not exist"

Tags: pacman

Tried

```
pacman -S postgresql
```

which returns

```
Warning: atabase file fir 'core' does not exist
...
error: target not found: postgresql
```

How do I install postgresql?

Comment: Did you copy that error by hand? What does `pacman -Syu`? You should always do `pacman -Syu` before you install new packages.

Comment: After -Syu the latest postgresql flocks right in. you solved it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to do `pacman -Syu` then `pacman -S postgresql`

The reason you have this type of error is because pacman doesn't have a list of available packages. `pacman -Syu` will update (or create) the available package list, then upgrade the currently installed packages.

Before installing you could use `pacman -Ss postgresql` to see a list of package matching your input, it will help you figure out which packages you need.

For more advanced list of pacman features, read the [Archwiki post about pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman)